# Data from javascript to python(using post)

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to give data from javascript to python, using post

On my Javascript

```
$('ABC').on("click", function(){
    $.post( '/user',
        {
            user: 'here'
        }
    )});
```

And giving this to python

```
@app.route("/user", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user():
    id = user
    return id
```

Above code should show html with just user.

But page does not move when on click..

Any idea?

Comment: What Python server framework are you using? You need to access the POST parameters; see its documentation.

Comment: any errors in `console`?

Comment: The page doesn't move because you're making an AJAX request. If you want the page to move, you need to submit a POST `<form>`.

Comment: @PedroLobito no errors in console..

Comment: @ChrisG I know how to use post method in <form> want to know how to do it from ajax

Comment: @SLaks Using Flask framework, yeah i saw documentation and other answers googling, but dont know the difference.

Comment: @임지웅 What exactly do you mean by "page does not move"? If you want something to happen after your POST request, you need to add a `success` callback to your `$.post()`

Comment: problem is when I post to '/user', i dont think it goes to '/user'

Comment: @ChrisG moving to /user shouldn't my page pop up 'id' with white page? Also using return render_template it does not work

Comment: AJAX doesn't update the page by itself. You need to provide a callback function in `$.post()` that updates the page with the result.

Comment: Like I said, if you want to see the id on a white page, you have to submit a POST form. Whether you do this by clicking a submit button or by submitting it using JS doesn't matter, but AJAX is the wrong tool here. An AJAX request will not navigate away from the current page, that's the whole point of AJAX, the reason why it is available in the first place. I don't know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a callback function in `$.post`

```
$('ABC').on("click", function() {
  $.post('/user', {
    user: 'here'
  }, function(response) {
    $("#result").html(response);
  });
});
```

You can also abbreviate this to the `.load()` method:

```
$('ABC').on("click", function() {
  $("#result").load('/user', {
    user: 'here'
  });
});
```