# Reloading full html code from response on current page

Tags: javascript, ajax

As I get full html code from python using render_template,

I want to reload full html code on current page.

I know I could use `form` method, and I know to use `$('#A').html(response)`

1. `form` method : I do not use submit button,, so this is not what i am looking for.
2. `$('#A').html(response)` : This adds the code from where id A. When using this code my full html code duplicate inside current page, not overwrapping

So, I need how to reload my current page with responed full html code

I also tried

```
$.post('/cccc',{user_id: id}, function(response){
        window.location.replace(html(response));
    }
);
```

But this also occur `html not defined` errors.

Can someone give me some help?

Comment: what does the response received looks like. console log response in function(response) and show me. It is the string containing html code, ie. `<html> .... </html>`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal its whole new html code starting from `<html>....</html>`

Comment: I'll simply insist that my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53643203/5734311) is *exactly* what you're looking for. You apparently haven't even tried my code, or you would see that it does exactly what you want. There's is no Submit button the user has to click in my solution. Everything is done invisibly to the user. It's not my fault if you don't even *try* it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data from javascript to python(using post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642615/data-from-javascript-to-pythonusing-post)

Comment: This is the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit which this one and the previous two are a duplicate of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `document.write()`

```
$.post('/cccc',{user_id: id}, function(response){
    document.open();
    document.write(response);
    document.close();
});
```

### Demo

```html
<html>
    <script>
     function replace(){
            const newhtml = '<html><body style="background-color: white"><p>New Content</p></body></html>';
            document.open()
            document.write(newhtml);
            document.close();
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <p>Old Content</p>
        <a href='javascript:replace()'>Replace</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vaibhavhrt/co14hu6z/)

Comment: oh thanks, hmm wierd i tried `document.write()` before but that time it did not work, now it is working thanks!